# Are different between 'RUN' and 'RUN (full) selection' in Spyder?

Tags: python, spyder

I have a source code consists of many custom modules.

In the first few lines, there are `import` words such as...

```
import custom_module_1
import custom_module_2
import custom_module_3
....
```

When I run(shortcut is F9) this code with partial or full selection, I found `ModuleNotFoundError: custom_module_1`.

However, when I run(F5) code, I works well  `runfile('C:/Users/user/Desktop/test.py', wdir='C:/Users/user/Desktop')`

I am so confused because I thought 'run(F5)' and 'full selection run(F9)' are same.

However the results are very different.

Is there any different between 'run(F5)' and 'full selection run(F9)' in Spyder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) The difference is the following:

- `Run selection` takes the code you've selected in the Editor, pastes it in the console and runs it.
- `Run file` is similar to executing `python myfile.py`, but before doing that it changes the directory your code will be run to the one your file is placed in. It'll also run it in a clean namespace so it's not affected by the variables currently defined in the console. Especially due to this last feature, you should avoid using `Run selection` as much as possible.

In your case I think the problem is that `Run selection` doesn't change directories, so Python can't find the modules you have next to `test.py`.